how to find the number of flow files from the input queue in apache nifi
I want to read number of flow files from a given input flow file as an argument, let say if my input queue contains three flow files, in my next processor i would like to read it as an argument

The number of FlowFiles in the queue can change at any moment, but if you want to know how many are available, then in a scripted processor such as ExecuteScript you can do something like def flowFiles = session.get(10000) (or some number bigger than the expected number of FlowFiles to be in the queue. The value of flowFiles?.size() is the number of available FlowFiles in the queue, but if you aren't processing any of them you'd need to transfer them all by calling session.transfer(flowFile.get(i), REL_SUCCESS) on each.
